# how to show certain amount of dates in FSCalendar in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, fscalendar

I am having an issue with `FSCalendar`.
In my project i have a tableview having a different type of `cell` one of them having a calendar which is `FScalendar`.

Now I want to show dates on the calendar and dates are coming from another `UITableviewCell` but its not working properly.

first time it works shows date but after that it disappears.

Comment: Can you please add some code or any images for better understanding.